# slurm: Sharing system resources dynamically across users

Tags: slurm, hpc

I am new to Slurm.

Let's say we have a computing system with 24 cores CPU & 32GB system memory.
I need to divide that system resources by each user in my job queue **dynamically**.

How should I set Slurm to achieve something like this:

If nothing is running in the cluster and one user put a job to the queue, give all the resources. (24C - 32GB)

If 2 users put their jobs to the queue and waiting to be executed, take them from the queue then share that resources by 12C - 16GB and run them simultaneously.

If 3 users put their jobs to the queue and waiting to be executed, take them from the queue then share that resources by 8C - 10.6GB and run them simultaneously.

If 4 users put their jobs to the queue and waiting to be executed, take them from the queue then share that resources by 6C - 8GB and run them simultaneously.

As you can see, I need to share my system resources by count of users **WAITING IN THE QUEUE** and run their jobs concurrently.